# how to fix this error?vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, wampserver

Here is the screen shot of the vb.net:
http://www.mypicx.com/12132009/ers/

And here is my code:

```
Dim connectionString As String = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=my school;" '
        Dim conn As New OdbcConnection(connectionString)
        conn.Open()
        Dim da As New OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT IDNUMBER, LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, MIDDLENAME COURSE FROM students", conn)


        conn.Close()
```

-All I want to do is to connect wamp server with vb.net, here is the version in wamp server

sql server : 5.1.36

Comment: I can't edit yet, but you should format the code by using 4 spaces infront of every line of code.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Need more information. Did you install that driver (get it from the MySQL website). Have you set up a database on your PC?

Comment: The solution to any VB.NET problem starts by switching to C#.

Comment: @Baddie: wow, helpful **and** funny. Of course, this problem would just go away by switching to C#. Clever!

Comment: Agreed. All the cool guys are doing C#.

Comment: Sarcasm - Doesn't work well on the net. Yet, I keep trying...

Comment: @Kobi, believe me that's not true. The cool guys are doing both languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of ODBC I would suggest you [downloading](http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/) the ADO.NET standard driver for MySQL and use it like this:

```
Dim connectionString As String = "Server=localhost;Database=my school;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;"
Using conn As New MySqlConnection(connectionString)
    Using da As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT IDNUMBER, LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, MIDDLENAME COURSE FROM students", conn)
        conn.Open()
        ' Do something with the results

    End Using
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> "Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=my school;"
> ```
>
> sql server : 5.1.36

You are using the wrong driver, namely one for a MySQL database. Your database is a SQL Server, so another driver is needed; try `"Driver={SQL Server}"` in the connection string instead (only a wild guess …).

Comment: I think MySQL is being used. There is no SQL Server version 5.1.36.

Comment: @Daniel: ouch, didn’t pay attention to the version number. Hmm … I still guess that the driver isn’t installed, though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using MySQL 5.1.36 and not SQL Server 5.1.36 (in which case it's really time for an upgrade) then you probably need to install [MySQL Connector/NET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net.html), these are the drivers that will let you connect to a MySQL database from a .NET application.

You'll then also be able to use the native MySQL data classes, such as MySqlConnection instead of the generic OdbcConnection.